# String[] to uint32 c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, arguments, uint

I am trying to convert `String[] args[1]` to `uint`, but I keep getting `System.FormatException`, any ideas on how I can fix this?

I'm converting with this code:

```
uint Offset = Convert.toUInt32(args[1]);
```

My `args[1]` is `0x026C0658`, but I want `0x026C0658` converted from `String[]`, to `uint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip of the prefix (`0x`) and tell it to use base 16:

```
var i = Convert.ToUInt32("026C0658", 16); // 40633944
```

The array factor is separate and unrelated.